# Scatter plot of 1-D bimodal data from sklearn make_blobs()

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, scatter-plot

sklearn `make_blobs()` function can be used to Generate isotropic Gaussian blobs for clustering.

I am trying to plot the data generated by `make_blobs()` function.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr, blob_labels = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=1, 
                                centers=1, random_state=1)
a = plt.hist(arr, bins=np.arange(int(np.min(arr))-1,int(np.max(arr))+1,0.5), width = 0.3)
```

this piece of code gives a normal distribution plot, which makes sense.

[image]

```
blobs, blob_labels = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, 
                                centers=2, random_state=1)

a = plt.scatter(blobs[:, 0], blobs[:, 1], c=blob_labels)
```

this piece of code gives a 2-clusters plot, which also makes sense.

[image]

I am wondering that is there a way to plot the data generated by `make_blobs()` function with params `centers=2 n_features=1`.

```
arr, blob_labels = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=1, 
                                centers=2, random_state=1)
```

I've tried `plt.hist()`, which gives another normal distribution plot.

I have no idea how to use `plt.scatter()` with the data.

I cannot image what the plot should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is somewhat unclear.

> I've tried `plt.hist()`, which gives another normal distribution plot.

Well, not exactly; it gives a *bimodal Gaussian mixture* plot:

```
arr, blob_labels = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=1, 
                                centers=2, random_state=1)

a = plt.hist(arr, bins=np.arange(int(np.min(arr))-1,int(np.max(arr))+1,0.5), width = 0.3)
```

[image]

as expected, since now we have `centers=2`.

> I have no idea how to use `plt.scatter()` with the data.

*By definition*, a scatter plot needs 2D data; from the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html):

> A scatter plot of *y* vs *x* with varying marker size and/or color.

while here, due to `n_features=1`, we actually have only *x* and no *y*.

A 1D "scatter plot" is actually a line, and we can use `plot` to visualize it, as nicely explained in [How to plot 1-d data at given y-value with pylab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352220/how-to-plot-1-d-data-at-given-y-value-with-pylab); in your case:

```
val = 0. # this is the value where you want the data to appear on the y-axis.
a = plt.plot(arr, np.zeros_like(arr) + val, 'x')
```

[image]

where of course we should keep in mind that the vertical axis is just a convenience for the visualization, and does not say anything for our data which have no *y* value whatsoever.

Want to use different colors and/or markers for each center?

```
val = 0. # this is the value where you want the data to appear on the y-axis.
plt.plot(arr[blob_labels==0], np.zeros_like(arr[blob_labels==0]) + val, 'x', color='y')
plt.plot(arr[blob_labels==1], np.zeros_like(arr[blob_labels==1]) + val, '+', color='b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

where for larger samples the situation starts getting somewhat more interesting; notice the overlap for `n_samples=10000`:

[image]